# howto slove Xampp is not working when installing

Tags: php, xampp

[after instroling when runing this error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hux5R.png)

how to make this ?error
Important! Because an activated User Account Control (UAC) on your system some functions of XAMPP are possibly restricted.

With UAC please avoid to install XAMPP to C:\Program Files(Missing Write permissions). Or Deactivate UAC with msconfig after this setup.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

For setting UAC on Windows OS

Please run "msconfig"

click "Tools" (the Tools Tab), choose "Change UAC Settings" , and click "launch"

You may choose "Never notify" if you wish

Comment: i will try it and see